# Correct node.js command to create gulpfile.js

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I'm using Node.js command prompt and I've been trying to get Gulp running in our existing e-learning project, to compile the scss files to css.

In Node.js, I've 'cd'ed to the root directory of the project.

I've run 'npm install', 'npm audit fix', 'npm install gulp' and 'npm install gulp-cli' (because installing gulp-cli globally threw errors). These all seem to have run without serious errors.

A check for 'gulp --version' returns:

CLI version: 2.3.0

Local version: 4.0.2

When I run 'gulp' I get the error 'no gulpfile found'.

When I run 'npm init', I get the short explanation that 'This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file...', which ends with 'Press C^ at any time to quit' but nothing happened and over an hour later I pressed CTRL+C to end the process.

What is the next step to enable us to compile the scss files to css, when they're updated?

Comment: Please let me know if this question is either too basic to reply to or too specific - or if there's some other problem. I honestly cannot tell.

Comment: Do you actually have a `gulpfile.js` file?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. If it's supposed to be in the project's root directory then 'no'. I will take any advice to progress this even just one step closer to compiling the scss. Thanks.